# In what files in the home dir does gnome store the user config data?

Tags: linux, backup, gnome, restore

In what files/dirs in the home dir does gnome store the user config data?

Or if you like.

What files do I need to restore from backup in order to restore 
my gnome desktop with all the different settings I made?

Thanks
Johan

---

*Edit*: 
All user config files is usually stored somewhere in /home/$USER/.
And since all the programs, kde, xfce and gnome stores their config there, this question is about what files belong to the gnome desktop.

---

*The file list:*

This is my guess of what files belong to the gnome desktop

- .gconf/
- .gconfd/
- .gnome2/
- .gnome2_private/
- .nautilus/

And some parts of

- .config/

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also don't forget ~/.config, which a lot of Gnome (and other) application use nowadays.

It's the ['XDG/freedesktop' standard location](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) , and usually configured to be at ~/.config

Ohh, but why just backup the whole home dir (or atleast all dot files and directories)?

Comment: I'm merging two home dirs into one. I have one nice xfce and one nice gnome. And I would like to have them both in the same computer :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's in your /home/"Username" directory, right click in the window and show hidden files, all folders starting with a . (fullstop) are hidden folders normally holding config.

Comment: Sorry, but can you be more precise? This answer mean that .vim and .Skype is part of the Gnome desktop?